# Zend Framework 2 - translating routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, routes, translate

I am wondering if it is possible to use translational tools for routes/uris in zf2. I want for example the route `en.domain.tld/article/show/1` to translate for example to `de.domain.tld/artikel/anzeigen/1`. I don't think regex is the way to go here, because it could result in something like `en.domain.tld/artikel/show/1`. Also I want to avoid creating routes for every language, because it is going to get quite messy as the system scales.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get it working!

First, add a `'router_class' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack',` your `module.config.php` like this:

```
return array (
    'router' => array (
        'router_class' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack',
        'routes' => array(),
    )
);
```

Second, you must provide a translator (preferably in your module.php) as well as a translation file:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // Load translator
       $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
       $translator->setLocale('de_DE');        

           // setup the translation file. you can use .mo files or whatever, check the translator api
           $translator->addTranslationFile('PhpArray', __DIR__.'/language/routes/de_DE.php', 'default', 'de_DE');

       $app      = $e->getTarget();

       // Route translator
       $app->getEventManager()->attach('route', array($this, 'onPreRoute'), 100);
    }

    public function onPreRoute($e){
        $app      = $e->getTarget();
        $serviceManager       = $app->getServiceManager();
        $serviceManager->get('router')->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
    }
}
```

now, you should be able to use translations in your route definitions like the following:

```
return array (
    'router' => array (
        'routes' => array(
            'login' => array (
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array (
                'route' => '/{login}',
                'defaults' => Array(
                    'controller' => '...',
                ) 
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

create the translation (in this example a phpArray located in module/language/routes/de_DE.php):

```
<?php
return array(
    'login' => 'anmelden',
);
```

If I didn't forget anything, you should be good to go. I got it working in my case, so if it doesn't with the instructions above, don't hesitate to comment and I'll sort things out.

Comment: This doesnt work with an additional console route, right?
`Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No translator provided'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a implementation already which you will find starting ZF 2.2.0. As far as i can tell there is no Documentation for this feature, however when looking at the unit tests you should be able to give this a shot:

- [`ZendTest\Mvc\Router\Http\SegmentTest`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/tests/ZendTest/Mvc/Router/Http/SegmentTest.php#L186)

I'll try to get a working example setup sometime today, but can't make any promises - the test should get you started tho!

Comment: that looks very promising and is definately worth a shot! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the onPreRoute callback above:

You may need to add:

$serviceManager->get('router')->setTranslatorTextDomain('**TEXT_DOMAIN_HERE**');

Comment: Upvoted this answer for giving me the idea of using a separate text domain just for URLs.